# Creating a reusable interface element in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

I'm developing a WPF application in C# and was thinking about implementing a custom UI element accross various windows.

I would like to have a minimized tray (only about 4px visible) that expands after clicking on an icon next to the tray. The expanded version would show all controls and would minimize when I click the icon again. I created a quick HTML [concept](http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/3884/conceptpu.png) to clarify things.

I know I could put a stackpanel and button in my application and making both of them move up when I click the button, but then I would need to duplicate the code a lot.

Though I'm experienced with C#, I'm fairly new to WPF interface development/templates, but I'm sure there has to be a way so I can use that UI element accross my application without needing to copy/paste a lot of lines of code in my form class file.

I hope someone can help me, or at least point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are three ways to customize your elements.

**1** If you only need visual modifications you can use **styles** to change the appearance of the .net default controls. You can even override / extend the default templates.

**2** If you want custom logic in a control you can create a **custom control**. The framework brings a lot of "primitives" to build upon. Examples are `ContentControl` or `HeaderedContentControl`. Say you want to build a custom expander control you can inherit your custom control from `HeaderedContentControl` which provides you with Header and Content properties and you just have to implement the toggling logic yourself.
CustomControls are a good choice if you want to build basic functionality which can be used throughout your application. They can be themed/styled depending on the use case, too (see 1).

**3** If you want to compose different controls into one control you can create a **UserControl**. User controls are composed using XAML. Most top level controls are user controls driven by a view model.

Your case can be build using a `Popup` and `ToggleButton` or an `Expander`.

The decision depends on the desired behavior. If you want the opened panel to move following content down you need a expander. If you want a dropdown like functionality you need popup.

If you use a popup just bind the `IsPopupOpen` Property to `IsChecked` of the ToggleButton and set `PopupStaysOpen = false` to wire the button to your popup.

If you use an expander control you should create a style which can be applied to all equal expanders in your application to minimize the required XAML in each view.

Answer (score 2):

How about using Expander Control?

Answer (score 0):

There's a control called an Expander that is perfect for this.  You'll have to style it to look like you want, however it has the functionality you want built-in.